# namenode failed to start in ambari

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, ambari

namenode failed to start via ambari.

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/HDFS/package/scripts/namenode.py", line 414, in <module>
    NameNode().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 353, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/HDFS/package/scripts/namenode.py", line 138, in start
    upgrade_suspended=params.upgrade_suspended, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/ambari_commons/os_family_impl.py", line 89, in thunk
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/HDFS/package/scripts/hdfs_namenode.py", line 115, in namenode
    format_namenode()
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/HDFS/package/scripts/hdfs_namenode.py", line 369, in format_namenode
    logoutput=True
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 263, in action_run
    returns=self.resource.returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 72, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep, timeout_kill_strategy=timeout_kill_strategy, returns=returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 314, in _call
    raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 'hdfs --config /usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/hadoop/conf namenode -format -nonInteractive' returned 1. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c8000000, 939524096, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 939524096 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hs_err_pid2526.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the machine you've installed it on has insufficient memory.

You'll need to add more RAM to it or adjust heap sizes of all processes on the machine

Answer (score 0):

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>   Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 939524096 bytes for committing reserved memory.

You need to allocate more RAM, because right now you don't have enough memory.

Comment: It would help, if you would also explain, how that can be done.